# Random tile-based map generation like Terraria in unity?

Tags: c#, random, dictionary, unity-game-engine, procedural

I would like to generate a map from tiles like in the games Terraria and Starbound using Unity and C#
What I have done so far isn't working and I have no idea why... Any help/ideas/suggestions?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MapGeneration : MonoBehaviour {
public int mapWidth, mapHeight, spreadDegree;
GameObject[,] blocks;
public GameObject baseBlock;

public int maxHeightAllowed;
public int nullDispersion;
int dispersionZone;

void Start() {
    GenerateMap();
}

void GenerateMap() {
    dispersionZone = maxHeightAllowed - nullDispersion;
    blocks = new GameObject[mapWidth, mapHeight];
    for(int x = 0; x < blocks.GetLength(0); x++) {
            for(int y = nullDispersion; y <= maxHeightAllowed; y++) {
                int heightDiff = y - nullDispersion;
                float dispersionModifier = Mathf.Sin( (heightDiff / dispersionZone) * 90);
                float random = Random.Range(0, 1);

                if(random > dispersionModifier) {
                    blocks[x,y] = (GameObject)Instantiate(baseBlock, new Vector2(x, y), Quaternion.identity);
                } else if (y < blocks.GetLength(1) && blocks[x,y+1] != null) {
                    blocks[x,y] = (GameObject)Instantiate(baseBlock, new Vector2(x, y), Quaternion.identity);
                }
            }

            for(int y = 0; y < nullDispersion; y++) {
                blocks[x,y] = (GameObject)Instantiate(baseBlock, new Vector2(x, y), Quaternion.identity);
            }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You need to say *what* isn't working. I just see a code dump so far.

Comment: Ah.. At the moment it just generates one solid block... It should create a random map like Terraria... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
(heightDiff / dispersionZone)
```

This is integer division. Use `(heightDiff / (float)dispersionZone)` instead.

```
* 90
```

`Mathf.Sin` works in radians, not degress. Use `* Math.PI/2`

```
            if(random > dispersionModifier) {
                blocks[x,y] = (GameObject)Instantiate(baseBlock, new Vector2(x, y), Quaternion.identity);
            } else if (y < blocks.GetLength(1) && blocks[x,y+1] != null) {
                blocks[x,y] = (GameObject)Instantiate(baseBlock, new Vector2(x, y), Quaternion.identity);
            }
```

Why are you using if, when you are creating same type of block? Shouldn't there be some kind of difference between the bodies in if and else?